# What is the equivalent of WebForms in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, webforms

I am doing my final year project in Computer Science and the project is a system for managing a college, like [openSIS](http://www.opensis.com), but using [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) to build it.

I need help on how to Add, Update, and Remove data using regular HTML forms, such as via `<form/>` and `<input type="submit"/>`. I knew how to do this in WebForms, but not in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Take a look to [MVC Core CRUD example](https://github.com/nreco/data/tree/master/examples/SqliteDemo.MVCApplication) (list, add/edit form) from NReco.Data project

Comment: Now maybe [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) is a choice?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you're asking to do is possible "out of the box" with [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) and does not require a third-party solution.

### Solution #1: ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

[Microsoft - Introduction to Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/)

This is probably the most direct approach with the least to learn, and it is the modern equivalent to "Classic ASP.NET Web Forms." You are probably asking about this:

The basic idea is you create an "ASP.NET Core Web Application" project in Visual Studio and select the "Web Application" project template (confirming that ".NET Core" is selected in the template selection dialog before you click OK.)

You can then add "Razor Pages" containing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and use a simple post-back method via a regular [HTML Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) with a Submit Button. The link above has [a topic on doing just that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio#writing-a-basic-form).

### Solution #2: ASP.NET Core MVC

[Microsoft - Overview of ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview)

This is the second-most direct approach but does require you to grasp MVC concepts: [Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding), [Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview) and [Controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions#what-is-a-controller).  Implementing Razor Pages would only require you to grasp HTML and Razor Page code-behind, however, MVC as a pattern will provide your resulting project with a more maintainable and testable approach to the project.

The basic idea is to scaffold an "ASP.NET Core Web Application" project in Visual Studio, then select the "Web Application (Model-View-Controller)" project template.

Instead of adding [Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/) you add [Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview), to do anything useful these [Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview) will have corresponding [Controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions#what-is-a-controller). There will also be [Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) defined, as you would see in a Razor Pages solution. In the case of MVC the [Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) are posted to your [Controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions#what-is-a-controller) via [Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions#defining-actions).

The link above covers the subject in detail, and there are numerous Stack Overflow posts on general MVC concepts.

### Solution #3: RESTful Web APIs and Client-Side JavaScript

[Microsoft - Building Web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/web-api/)

This is probably the least direct and most-technical approach. You will want to be familiar with "JavaScript" and "XHRs", "JSON" (or XML, but JSON has become de facto), and you will want to be versed in what it means to be a "RESTful Web Service" ie. that HTTP supports basic verbs to POST, GET, and DELETE a resource.

The basic idea is you create an "ASP.NET Core Web Application" project in Visual Studio using the MVC scaffold. You then implement [Controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions#what-is-a-controller) to behave as RESTful web services. You can add Razor Pages and/or MVC [Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview) to deliver the HTML and JavaScript.

With this approach you can create "Single-Page Applications" that never need to reload, where the HTML and JavaScript for the entire application can be delivered up-front and then RESTful web services used to modify the UI at the client. This can get advanced, and most developers will want to look into using a client-side templating engine. The leanest and simplest to use is probably going to be KnockoutJS, but others are more popular (and more complex.) Knockout has the value of solving a very specific problem: data-binding an HTML UI to JavaScript objects.

Regardless of the approach you take, start here: [Microsoft - Get Started with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started)

Comment: @ShaunWilson - Microsoft has not released a SSRS Report Viewer for ASP.NET Core or MVC 5; which leaves us with Web Forms. Is it possible to host/execute Web Forms within an ASP.NET core project? Similar in that MVC 5 could host Web Forms? For example, if I ran ASP.NET core using .NET Framework 4.7.2 - could I also host a Web Form within that site?

Comment: @VAUser1 The answer to this sort of question should always be "yes, it's possible" because it's an engineering problem; though it would be "unusual", and as these are two separate stacks "a site in IIS could leverage both frameworks" but the stacks would not be truly intermingled. Separately, there is [Alan Juden's Report Viewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AlanJuden.MvcReportViewer.NetCore/) for .NET Core, however, I have no personal experience with this component.. the community responses suggest it would be worth looking into.

Comment: @VAUser1 Lastly, an `<iframe/>` and dedicated app(s)/host(s) for report gen has ancillary benefits in resource management vs. the main site, I would not disregard such a solution if scale or compute-power are issues (much like applying "SRP" to your service architecture.)

Answer (score 16):

If you like the Web Forms way of development, or if you have a large ASP.NET Web Forms application and you need to implement new pages in it, you can try [DotVVM](https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm).

It is not "Web Forms on .NET Core", but:

- many concepts in DotVVM are similar to ASP.NET Web Forms (postbacks, server controls, master pages, even the names of the controls and page lifecycle events)
- it is *easy to learn* for ASP.NET Web Forms developers
- no cryptic viewstate hidden field
- the controls don't produce ugly HTML
- the *MVVM pattern* is used
- no need to know or write JavaScript - C#, HTML and CSS is enough to start coding
- DotVVM supports both *.NET Core* and *full .NET Framework*
- can be added to existing ASP.NET Web Forms or MVC applications on .NET Framework
- DotVVM is [open source](https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm)
- [Visual Studio extension with IntelliSense and project templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomasHerceg.DotVVMforVisualStudio-17892)

*Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of DotVVM. This post is not meant to advertise the project, I just believe it responds to the question because the main motivation to build DotVVM was the fact that Web Forms are not ported to ASP.NET Core, and many people is looking for the similar way of building web applications. DotVVM is not a port of Web Forms to .NET Core. Our intent is to build a framework which is conceptually similar, but which avoids the things Web Forms were criticized for (viewstate, testability and ugly HTML output).*

- [DotVVM GitHub](https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm)
- [Documentation](https://www.dotvvm.com/docs)
- [Gitter Chat](https://gitter.im/riganti/dotvvm)

Answer (score 6):

If you are referring to WebForms from ASP.NET (before MVC webstack came), there is no WebForms for ASP.NET Core and unlikely to ever be ported.

There is however a similar project (usually referred as Razor Pages or View Pages, see [RazorPages](https://github.com/aspnet/RazorPages) GitHub repository) which allows to create Razor views which are not backed by a controller.

But as far as I know it's not release ready (there is no nuget package for it on nuget.org) and you'd have to use some previous from nightly builds or stable myget repositories.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 for Mac provides a template named 'ASP.NET Web Forms Project' which seems to provide most of the classic ASP.NET components.

Comment: @PhilipJespersen I see ASP.NET Web Forms in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows as well but only for .NET Framework 4.7.2 and lower. I don't believe it will be present for Core. I only see ASP.NET Core Web Application, no Web Forms template present on my PC.

Comment: @JeffMergler: There are no plans to port WebForms. The official alternative (for new projects) is to use ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Comment: The Webforms template works in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac, so it must be using .NET Core in Mac.

Comment: @FernandoGonzalezSanchez .NET Core is fully compatible with .NET Framework, so this is not surprising.

Comment: @TylerH: No, there are a lot of APIs that are not present in (ASP).NET Core  and .NET 5. WebForms, `System.Web`, Webservices, Workflow Foundation to name a few.

Comment: @Tseng That's not really what I meant. ASP.NET Core runs on .NET Framework, but it's true you would have to target Core versions before 3.0

Comment: @TylerH: I think there's a misunderstanding. ASP.NET Core doesn't have WebForms and never will, no matter if you run it on .NET Core or .NET Framework. ASP.NET Core is a complete rewrite vom ASP.NET . And the comment from Fernando is probably referring to WebForms with Mono (Linux Port of .NET Framework), which is possible but not very fast and with limited compatibility . Visual Studio 2019 for Mac is a rebranded Xamarin/Mono Studio (Xamarin being mobile successor of Mono), so it naturally supports the Mono build Environment. But Mono has nothing too do wwith .NET Core (or .NET 5)