# How can I add different controls dynamically to a web page using asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to .net core - have been using aspx web pages and .net framework 4.x for a number of years.  I have a project where we want to display different controls (textbox, dropdown, checkbox) on the page based on values returned from a query.  For example, user chooses "A" from a dropdown list and it shows 10 controls, if they choose object B it shows 8 controls, etc.  Previously in .net framework, I would use a content placeholder with an ID and then find that ID and start adding controls (controls.Add(newControl)) in the placeholder.  It doesn't seem that is an option with .net core.  It seems like this would be a common need for various web applications, but I'm not finding many hits.

Another question is whether this can be done in the code behind or if it has to be done on the client-side.  If one of the controls in the list is a dropdown, there will be a query that a subroutine will run to get the Key/Value pairs for the dropdown.  To me this means it would be more effective on the server side.

I haven't really found any good examples when I do some searching.  Can anyone point me to a good resource or provide me with a basic example - either client-side or server-side?  Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599341/what-is-the-equivalent-of-webforms-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this question related to web technology? this is not 100% clear. If yes, you should precise it, and maybe add an ASP.NET Core tag.
I will call forms the different group of controls you want to display depending on the user choice. Are the forms known at compile time, or at runtime?

Comment: Laurent, yes this is a web app.  I will add the ASP.NET Core tag.  The forms are only known at runtime.  The "forms" are pulled from the database.  The previous page will call this new page with a ProgramId.  When the new page loads, it calls a stored proc to get a list of "features" for that ProgramId.  Different programs have different features so the list coming back from the stored procedure is unknown in size and is the list of forms that need to be added to the page for this ProgramId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options, but I'll describe a simple one, using server side processing. As you explained in your comment, there will be 2 pages:

- One that will display the select element that will be used to choose a set of controls.
- The page that will be returned according to the previous choise, displaying the selected set of controls.

I assume that you know how to build the first page.

For the second page, you can leverage the ASP.NET Core MVC pattern to achieve the desired result.

You will need the three usual MVC elements:

- An Action in a Controler.
- A ViewModel for your Razor View.
- A Razor View.

The Action does the following:

- Receives the id of the selected set of control (via the Action's parameter).
- Uses this id to retrieve the information about the corresponding set of controls from your repository.
- Builds a ViewModel out of the received information.
- Builds a View using the obtained ViewModel.
- Return the builded View.

Here is some simplified example code:

In your controller, add the following method:

```
#!lang-cs

Public IActionResult GetProgramControlSet(int ProgramId)
{
    // Here, use the id to get the data from your repository
    // that will be used to build set of controls.
    // Supposing you have defined a GetControls method,
    // it could look like:
    var SelectedControls = MyRepository.GetControls(ProgramId);
    // If needed, you can build a ViewModel out of the received SelectedControls.
    var SelectedControlsViewModel = new ControlSetViewModel(SelectedControls);

    return View(SelectedControlsViewModel)
}
```

Of course, many things are missing here: error handling, etc...

Here is what the ViewModel could be:

```
#!lang-cs

public class ControlSetViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<IControl> Controls { get; private set; }

    public ControlSetViewModel(...)
    {
        // Whatever needs to be done to construct the ViewModel
    }
}

public enum ControlKind
{
    Button,
    Select,
    Textarea
    //...
}

public interface IControl
{
    ControlKind Kind { get; }
}

public class ControlButton : IControl
{
    public ControlKind Kind => ControlKind.Button;
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    // ... All other needed properties for the button
}

public class ControlTextarea : IControl
{
    public ControlKind Kind => ControlKind.Textarea;
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string PlaceholderText { get; set; }
    public string RowCount { get; set; }
    // ... All other needed properties for the textarea
}

public class ControlSelect : IControl
{
    public ControlKind Kind => ControlKind.Select;
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string PlaceholderText { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> Options { get; set; }
    // ... All other needed properties for the select
}

public class SelectOption
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value  { get; set; } 
}
```

You could also use inheritance instead of interface for the control classes.

Now the view.
It is a Razor page containing something akin to

```
@model ControlSetViewModel

@*... some HTML ...*@

<div>
<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
@foreach(var control in Model.Controls)
{
    <div>
    switch(control.GetControlKind())
    {
        case ControlKind.TextArea:
            var Textarea = (ControlTextarea)control;
            <label>@Textarea.Label</label>
            <textarea rows="@Textarea.RowCount"/>
            break;

        case ControlKind.Select:
            var Select = (ControlSelect)control;
            <label>@Select.Label</label>
            <select>
                @foreach(var option in Select.Options)
                {
                    <option value="@option.Value">@option.Text</option>
                }
            </select>
            break;
        @*... etc ...*@

        default:
        @*... etc ...*@
    }
    </div>
}
</div>
@*...  More HTML  ...*@
```

Of course this is far to be finished. All the infrastructure and code that will actually react to the displayed controls is missing.
Is it a form you that will be posted?
Is it Javascript code that will react to the control manipulation?
Or another mecanism?
This questions will need to be addressed.

Comment: This is great Laurent!  My thinking has been more or mimicking the old pattern of .net of finding the container control (like a panel) and doing a panel.Controls.Add() in the code behind in the Page_Load().  Your example helps me grasp the new pattern of using the model and the view to do what I need.  With using the Razor "code" I can have the switch statement do what I thought I had to do in the code behind.  (NOTE: I guess I don't have enough reputation point to vote on the answer, but I'm sure this will work for me.)

Comment: I’m glad I could help. Maybe you could try to edit your question in order to make it more clear, for instance by changing the title to « how can I add different controls dynamically to a web page using ASP .NET Core », and in the body, pointing that you are used to aspx (?) pages logic (or whatever was what you described). Then the question will be more valuable for others, and I’ll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Laurent, I have made some edits.  If you have any other things that I should clarify, let me know.  Thanks again for your really good answer/example.