# System.Web.UI not supported in .Net 8.0

Tags: .net-8.0

I have upgraded my project from `.Net 4.8` to `.Net8`, after upgrading I am getting errors related to `System.Web.UI`. Can someone suggest how I can resolve this or what is the alternative of `System.Web.UI` in `.Net8`?

Found some articles but are not useful.Screenshot of the error I got:

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to replace that was in System.Web.UI ?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot including the error message that you are facing now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599341/what-is-the-equivalent-of-webforms-in-asp-net-core

Comment: There's no alternative. WebForms was never migrated to .NET Core and .NET 8 is .NET *Core* 8 nor are there any plans or community projects for this. There's no interest. WebForms was already a legacy application by 2012. Even the [WebForms Migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/web_forms?view=aspnetcore-8.0) only shows how to use the legacy WebForms app side-by-side with a new ASP.NET Core project

Comment: @J.Memisevic, I have a GridView and HTMLControls in 4.8 framework which is giving error in 8.0. Need to replace that.